# Rhodes v/s Titanium

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, titanium, rhodes

Which is the best framework to develop cross platform application. Especially for android and iphone. I have been through the reviews present over the internet, but those seem to be pretty old. I believe both Titanium and Rhodes have developed much over the past couple of years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the basic differences is the nativeness of the two frameworks.  Both Rhodes Framework and Titanium claim to be *native*. Rhodes however is not really native i.e. it uses an embedded Web Browser to display the HTML-coded website. Titanium, however, takes your JavaScript code, and create real native widgets on the respective platforms.

So what's so important about native? Well, it makes the user experience **a whole lot better**.

Rhodes Framework is best described as a competitor to PhoneGap.

From my knowledge, Rhodes is best for enterprisey apps. **I would generally recommended Titanium for most app developers.**

Comment: u r right about rhodes using a browser component internally to display. i am afraid people who read this might think that rhodes apps take you to the browser. i agree that native look is important. but i am also not sure if the way to achieve native look matters for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not used Rhodes, I feel Titanium is better based on what I read about Rhodes. The JS syntax in Titaniums is also easy to ramp up on. But, from what I have seen, understanding the working of the native code is useful to understand and explain some of the behavior. There is one more comparison of the frameworks that I found recently [here](http://www.amlcode.com/2010/07/16/comparison-appinventor-rhomobile-phonegap-appcelerator-webview-and-aml/).

Comment: Yes it is. Edited. Just wanted to indicate the objects available in browser environment are not available, since there is a lot of confusion around JS frameworks that are used in hybrid applications vs the ones like Titanium where JS language is used to build the application, but compiled into native code